# continuousAutoFocus or autoFocus when tap to focus?

Tags: ios, swift, focus, avfoundation

The developing camera app uses `.autoFocus` when tap to focus, but considering using `.continuousAutoFocus` instead. Just don't know which is better? when will the tapPoint be dismissed? Does `.continuousAutoFocus` costs more battery?

```
if device.isFocusModeSupported(.continuousAutoFocus) {
      device.focusPointOfInterest = tapPoint
      device.focusMode = .continuousAutoFocus
}
```